# Copying "visualization_msgs::MarkerArray" as a vector

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attemping to copy that message over the topic `visualization_msgs::MarkerArray` with a function like this:

```
void myclass::incomingPoints( const visualization_msgs::MarkerArray &waypoints ) 
{
    goals.reserve( waypoints->markers.size() );
    copy( waypoints->markers.begin(), waypoints->markers.end(), back_inserter( goals ) );
}
```

where:

```
std::vector<visualization_msgs::Marker> goals;
```

But trying to compile I get the error that says:
.begin(), .size(), and .end() are not defined in the

```
visualization_msgs::Marker
```

> error: base operand of ‘->’ has
> non-pointer type ‘const MarkerArray
> {aka const
> visualization_msgs::MarkerArray_std::allocator<void
>
> > }’    goals.reserve( waypoints->markers.size() );

and that's ok, because they are in the class vector defined.
But how can I copy that array?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197064/copying-%22visualization_msgs::markerarray%22-as-a-vector/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I can answer myself.

I discoevered the using such function signature:

```
void myclass::incomingPoints( const visualization_msgs::MarkerArray &waypoints ) 
{
    goals.reserve( waypoints.markers.size() );    <---- Note the point!!!
    copy( waypoints.markers.begin(), waypoints.markers.end(), back_inserter( goals ) );   <---- Note the point!!!
}
```

it compiles

And changing the  signature to:

```
void myclass::incomingPoints( const visualization_msgs::MarkerArray::ConstPtr &waypoints ) 
{
    goals.reserve( waypoints->markers.size() );    <---- Note the arrow
    copy( waypoints->markers.begin(), waypoints->markers.end(), back_inserter( goals ) );   <---- Note the arrow
}
```

even works.

Function signature and called method must also match.

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1